# Regular / Singular points of the Hom scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $ X $ and $ Y $ be two projective varieties over $ \mathbb{C} $. One knows, from a result of Grothendieck, about the existence of a (quasi-projective) scheme $ \mathcal{Hom}(X,Y) $ which represents the functor $ T \rightarrow \text{Hom}(X \times T, Y) $ i.e. morphisms from $ X $ to $ Y $ parametrized by $ T $.

Let $ p : \operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{Hom}(X,Y) $ be a closed point corresponding to a morphism $ f : X \rightarrow Y $. Can we determine if $ p $ is a regular point or a singular point of the Hom scheme in terms of $ f $?

Comment: One way to approach those questions is to note that the tangent space of $\mathcal Hom(X,Y)$ at $f$ consists of $\operatorname Spec \mathbb C[\epsilon]/(\epsilon^2)$-valued points which restrict to $f$ for $\epsilon = 0$.

Comment: Yes, the tangent space in this case is $ H^0(X, f^*T_Y) $ - needs some arguments obviously, but we'll admit that. Then what? We need to check that this has the correct dimension, no?